# How can I compute the average request duration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, request, duration, sizing

I need to do some sizing evaluation for my application, and one key metric is the average request duration.

Is there a way I can run my tests (not using Rspecs) And that the framework can tell me the average time it takes for a request to go through, and tell me what are the slowest requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of tools to help with benchmarking... see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html for a starting point.

If your app is live, maybe give something like [new relic](http://www.newrelic.com/) a try as well. It's a very useful tool!

Comment: Thanks, just installed new relic on my heroku account, one click... and get into performance tests, I guess I could have looked harder, but this may help someone else!